# как вывести таблицу в python docx несколько раз?

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

```
import docx
from copy import deepcopy

document1 = docx.Document('path')
template = document.tables[0]
tbl = template._tbl
new_tabl = deepcopy(tbl)
document2 = docx.Document('path\\Билеты.docx')
for i in range(10):
    par = document2.add_paragraph()
    par._p.addnext(new_tabl)
```

я хочу вывести 10 скопированных таблиц из другого документа, но единственный метод, который я нашел чтобы вставить таблицу это "addnext", который выведет только одну в конце. Какой мне нужен метод для того, чтобы вывести все таблицы? В документации и на других форумах ничего не нашел

Answer (score 0):

Берешь нужную таблицу из tables документа по его id и вставляешь в документ _tbl через deepcopy

```
document._body._element._insert_tbl(deepcopy(document.tables[id]._tbl))
```